# Video Card Recommendation for Old MotherBoard

Tags: graphics-cards, motherboard

I hope everything is well.
Sorry if this question is too obvious, I am new in the world of computer hardware and I could not decide by my own.

I have an old PC whose mother board model is A8R-MVP. Originally, it was using a Radeon X1300Pro 256MB video card, but I need to change the video card. However, the company that used to manufacture that video card does not exist any more. Now I wonder of you could let me know what video cards might be compatible with this mother board, or at least how I can figure that out.

Thank you very much!

Comment: It looks like that board has PCI-Express, and almost all video cards are backwards compatible with the older PCIe ports. There's a good chance almost any video card you can buy now will work with that PC. Other things you need to tell us are what Operating System the PC has and wattage of the power supply though. (And whether the power supply has the PCI-Express power connectors for video cards)

Comment: Radeon still exists though, but it doesn't belong to ATI anymore. And indeed, what kinda PSU do you have?

Answer (score 2):

https://www.asus.com/us/SupportOnly/A8R-MVP/HelpDesk_Manual/

https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/socket939/A8R-MVP/e2319_a8r-mvp.pdf

see page 2-3 for mobo layout, it has a total of 6 PCI slots... 2 PCIE and 3 PCI (not PCIE) and one pciex1.

the second slot down from the top most slot is PCIE X16_1.   The top one being `PCIE X16_2`.  It has two x16 pcie slots.

> page 2-16
>
> This motherboard supports two ATI CrossFire™ PCI Express x16 graphics cards that comply with the PCI Express specifications. The figure shows two graphics cards installed on the PCI Express x16 slots.

so not too shabby for an old board.  Would it support two Nvidia cards, I don't know.  But it would support any one PCIE type graphics card either nvidia or ATI/AMD.

I did not find if it supports PCIE 1.0 or 2.0 or 3.0, but in any case any late model PCIE graphics card that is PCIE 3.0 or 4.0 will work.  From there it is a matter of if your Power Supply supplies supplemental pcie 6-pin or 8-pin power to the graphics card for whether or not you could get a high end double width type video card like an nvidia RTX3060.

see https://videocardbenchmarks.net and https://pcmecca.com/best-low-power-graphics-cards-without-external-power/

https://www.gpumag.com/gpu-power-connectors-explained/

https://www.cgdirector.com/gpu-power-cable-guide/

p.s. everything is well except for my ssh problem :)